# How to push the footer to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to align footer (div) to the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)
>   http://www.google.com/#q=bottom+footer+site:stackoverflow.com

How to push the footer to the bottom of the page ?

I tried many ways but nothing works :)

My Html

```
<div id="header">
.
.
</div>

<div id="container">
.
.
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerContent">
.
.
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.doturbo.com/test/404.html

http://www.doturbo.com/test/contact.html

Comment: You need a sticky footer 1 - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ 2 - http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html 3 - http://css-tricks.com/14-sticky-footer/ - I myself use 2

Answer (score 2):

I found the method linked below to be the most effective for my personal needs:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: I tried this way. It didn't work :)

Comment: @faressoft: Why this does not work? This is the most "quick" solution. However it has it's own problems, like when the content increases, it will overlap the footer. Give your html, body a height of 100%, give the <div id="wrapper> a height of 100% and a position of relative. Give the <div id="footer"> a position of absolute with bottom: 0px;