# How to move text to the bottom of the page even if page is long or short?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert the copyright information on the bottom of the page. If the page is empty, meaning that the content doesn't scroll the page. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgenS/)

How to move the text to the very bottom of the page, while keeping it below the page content?

Edit, if page is empty, I want the text to still appear by bottom border of the web browser.

Comment: This question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: apparently web designers call this pattern "sticky footer." Given tha, you can find quite a few step-by-step guides from experts via a web search engine, likewise (at least) a couple of excellent answers on SO.

Comment: @HelpNeeder I have trouble understanding what the difference between the solutions in the comments and your requirement is. It would help if you could make that more clear.

Comment: Please look at another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdJkr/). There's a scroll bar even if page is on the bottom. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please have a look on this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JCEFQ/ It might help in your situation.

Comment: @xsl, I kind of get it and almost got it working.

Comment: I'm sorry, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdJkr/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar will not be displayed if your remove the `margin` property from the `body_pages` class. See: http://jsfiddle.net/gdJkr/3/

Comment: Yes, I have noticed just now lol. Ok then the sticky footer works perfect :) Thank you for help.