# placed a footer bottom with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want place my footer on bottom screen like position: fixed and bottom 0 if there is not enough content. But when there is more content I want the footer after the content and not fixed at bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
    Bla
</div>
<div id="footer">sdfasdf</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header { background-color: gray; padding: 10px;}
#footer { background-color: black; padding: 10px;  color:white;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FJWZu/

In this case you see in the jsfiddle I want the footer at bottom.

Is there a way to achieve this without JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align footer (div) to the bottom of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Is your header and footer a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should search Google for *responsive design* which could give you some insights about those kind of behaviors.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) for example allows doing such things.
You have the [Sticky footer](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html), based on the Twitter Bootstrap that seems to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ I think it's what you want. A sticky footer.
`You have to set your content at min-height: 100%; eventually height: 100%, and set your html, body to: height: 100% too.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated css with [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/FJWZu/7/)

```
#footer { background-color: black; padding: 10px;  color:white; position: absolute;
    width: 96%;bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeah that's possible, this uses only `css` with `absolute` positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/FJWZu/3/