# Sticking my footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, sticky-footer

My footer doesn't want to stick to the bottom of the page. I'm new to HTML and I cant get it to go down.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2013. All rights reserved
</div>
```

Comment: What CSS is in your footer class?

Comment: This question has a duplicate. [Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3443606/1371589)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Fixed Solution:

```
.footer {
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Simple Absolute Solution:

```
.footer {
   position: absolute; 
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Fancier Sticky Footer:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions on Stack Overflow like this, one such question is the following:

[How to align footer (div) to the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

... and [I've given an answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page/3525675#3525675).

If you don't feel like navigating to the answer, here's two quick links:

- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/